# where is max.partition.fetch.bytes value in kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Where is max.partition.fetch.bytes value in Kafka consumer?

I have not found any variable name max.partition.fetch.bytes in Kafka consumer.properties file.

Kindly help me how to change the max.partition.fetch.bytes value in Kafka consumer 
Thanks.

Comment: ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG which Kafkka version u are using

Comment: kafka version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

There are more configurations than only those shown in the provided consumer properties file

They're all added the same way, and hopefully you already have at least bootstrap servers defined

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

You can also use the constants defined in `ConsumerConfig` class